# Shadow map artifacts

Tags: xna, c#, shaders, shadows, shadow-mapping

I want to try adding shadows to a 3D XNA game. I've set up some testing environment with one light and one camera. However, I'm running into artifacts with my approach.

I'm using the shader code from http://pastebin.com/zXi0hmsU to render the final result and http://pastebin.com/rY4Gcj9N to create the shadow maps. The code is pretty straight forward and involves production of the depthmap from the light point of view, then projecting it into the camera space and checking for occlusions.

However, from most angles I am getting pretty ugly results[image: like in this screenshot]

The scene consists of some simple cubes (constructed by hand, facing outside, backface is culled), one light (shadow map shown in top left corner - looks okay) and one camera.

My RenderTarget for the shadow maps is initialized by

```
int shadowMapSize = 512;
RenderTarget2D shadowMap = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, shadowMapSize,
    shadowMapSize, true, GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat,
    DepthFormat.Depth24Stencil8);
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(shadowMap);
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
```

Afterwards, the `CreateShadowMap` effect is applied, followed by the LambertWithShadows effect. Finally, the shadow map is drawn using a `SpriteBatch`.

Rest of the code consists of simply providing the correct values to the shaders. If necessary, I can provide it at well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is typical problem called *shadow map acne*. It is caused because of the projected pixel of the shadow map(depth) is bigger than pixel on the screen (eq. cannot represent depth correctly).

[image]

There are plenty of solutions to this. First most easy is bias (i see it in your code, so that is not the problem). And second easy solution is shadow map in bigger resolution, it is really more than typical to have shadowmaps in resolution 2048x2048 on current hw. *(EDIT: thats not true, i've wrote that when i was working on movie rendering. In game development, you want to keep you shadow map as small as possible)*

Some resources to study more advanced techniques.

- [Common Techniques to Improve Shadow Depth Maps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416324%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Gradient shadow maps](http://www.slideshare.net/ohyecloudy/42-eliminating-surface-acne-with-gradient-shadow-mapping)

---

edit:

- [Shadow Mapping: GPU-based Tips and Techniques](http://developer.amd.com/media/gpu_assets/Isidoro-ShadowMapping.pdf) - whole presentation is interesting, but very on-topic is the part starting with "Two Components of Bias". That Jacobians really helps (on same resolution of depth map)
- [Cascade shadow maps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416307%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - Very helpfull and useful.

Comment: I have some more materials on this topic in work, if you are interested i will share it too.

Comment: The main problem with big resolutions is that in the end game I have about 3-4 lights which are undirected => I will have to use cubic shadow maps there, which results in 24 shadowmaps. If you have additional materials, I would really appretiate your effort of sharing it with me :-)

Comment: I am interested at the least if that matters :)

Comment: @Etan. Yeah omni directional lights are real pain if talkin about shadows. (i know something about it :) http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6203/point-light-soft-shadows). Try to use dual paraboloid maps. Or if you like cubemaps, try to save some space by frustum-camera_frustum intersection culling for every face/render. You propably won't need shadow for all directions all the time (especially in exteriors)

Comment: @James I'll do my best in trying to not forget it :)

Comment: @Etan @James I added some more stuff for you. Both is worth reading if you are interested on this topic.

Comment: An easy trick is to draw backfaces into the shadow map instead of front faces.  You still have shadow acne, but it's on the dark side of the object, so you can't tell.

You can still get acne on thin objects, though, and it can cause problems if you have any wrap lighting (lighting that goes around to the dark side of the object, e.g. a cheap subsurface effect).

Comment: @Nathan It really does not sound that this will work to me:). If you save the depth of backfaces when creating shadow map, front faces will be in shadow, isnt that right?

Comment: No, they won't, because the front faces are closer to the light than the depth in the shadow map at that point.